# Ajax - download file with headers

Tags: javascript, c#

In my server side I am using `C#` `MVC` and I have the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetPulledFile(string sha256)
{
    string localPath = string.Format("{0}\\pulledFiles\\{1}", Settings.LocalPath, sha256);
    if(!System.IO.File.Exists(localPath))
    {
        return Content("File does not exists");
    }

    return new FilePathResult(localPath, "application/octet-stream") { FileDownloadName = sha256 };
}
```

And on my `javascript` code I add before:

```
window.location = `${config.config.SERVER_URL}/WebApp/Files/GetPulledFile?sha256=${rowData.sha256}`;
```

This works.

Now the thing is that I added token validation on the server side, which means every client side request must come with a `Token` header inside it!

How can I send an `GET` ajax request with `headers` and receive as a response a `application/octet-stream`.

My main problem is that the file exists outside the Site location

Comment: If you use `window.location` to make a request to the server, you won't be able to set any headers. This will always result in a simple HTTP GET request without any header customization.

Comment: "using AJAX"...and when that file content is delivered into a JavaScript variable representing the response from your server, what are you going to do with it? You can't save it to the user's disk from there. AJAX is really not suitable for file downloads. If the user is logged into the application browser already, will it not send their token automatically (from their login cookie) if they simply navigate to the URL?

Comment: @ADyson So what do you advise? I need to send a header token, otherwise anyone can access this folder

Comment: Read the last part of my comment again

Comment: before it used a cookie, but I changed it to a client side token, since a cookie is CSRF valnurable

Comment: what token scheme are you using exactly? TBH a token scheme isn't a great fit for a GUI application where you need to make conventional GET requests. Cookies exist for a reason. They don't have to be CSRF vulnerable, if you do it right. Lots of sites set CSRF tokens, for instance. Lots of frameworks, such as ASP.NET, provide built-in functionality to do it. Anyhow, CSRF isn't much of an issue with a request like this, there's no form submission taking place. There's no side effect to the action - the user is either logged in, or not. The request doesn't try to change the application's state.

Comment: Where does it say TBH isn't good for GUIs? everything works great other then this scenario, must be a way to do this simple thing. Maybe for this specific requests I will use a cookie. BTW my website uses is an `MVC` on the server side and react on the  client side

Comment: in that case you can easily add CSRF protection where needed, MVC has facilities for it already. The reason the purely token-based approach isn't great for traditional web apps is precisely this scenario you're facing now - making a GET request without using AJAX.